# Adding xsi:schemaLocation without xmlns:xsi vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a request it's a XML with the namespace and the schema like this:

```
-eu:Addenda xsi:schemaLocation=[URI] [FILE.xsd] xmlns:eu=[URI]
```

However I create this

```
-eu:Addenda xmlns:xsi=[URI] xmlns:eu=[URI] xsi:schemaLocation=[URI FILE.xsd]
```

The XML that I have created has an extra node. So they tell me that's wrong. If I remove this extra node I have an error. So I want to know what can I do?
The attribute that doesn't have to appear is `xmlns:xsi=[URI]`

Can anybody help me?

```
Set objDom = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
ns = [URI] 
xsi = [URI file.xsd]
Set objRoot = objDom.createNode(1, "eu:Addenda", ns) 

objRoot.setAttribute "xsi:schemaLocation",[URI] [file.xsd]
objRoot.setAttribute "xmlns:eu",[URI]
objRoot.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi",[URI]
```

Comment: *"The attribute that doesn't have to appear is `xmlns:xsi=[URI]`"*. -- Why do you think that? Of course it has to appear.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I know that the attribute has to appear, but the people that validate the XML file they said that is wrong and they rejected it. So I have to change the header. ¿What can I do?

Comment: Tell them that they don't know what they are talking about and show them that the XML validates against an XML parser.